# Flip UIView with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer, flip

I need to flip a view when the user swipes from right to left. If I use this code

```
UIView.transitionFromView(firstView, toView: secondView, duration: timeInterval, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
```

I will achieve the desired animation. However I need to control the amount that is flipped not via a duration but via the amount of translation in a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

How could I do this?

EDIT:- I am looking for the animation in the below link but I need to be able to control it with a PanGesture

http://www.code4app.net/ios/Objective-C-UIView-subclass-that-flips-like-a-double-sided-coin-between-two-view/526754e16803fadf49000000

Thanks

Comment: Use CoreAnimation instead, CALayer has transform property, it's look more realistic than UIKit transform.

Comment: Thanks @TiepVuVan . Are you referring to CATransform3DMakeRotation ? How would I get the other view to show up as this rotates?